# changing a URL for Excel Web Query

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that gets information from a data connection. On the properties of the connection is the "connection string" which is a URL with several parameters that are passed to the server in the query string. If you click "edit query" you can change the URL and then import new data based on the new URL. I need to do this via VBA.

Let's say the connection string is currently `http://myserver.com?name=foo`
I need to change that to `http://myserver.com?name=bar`

How can this be done?

Comment: [Connection strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_string) and URLs are completely different things.

Comment: do you mean that this is a 'web query'?

Comment: Uhm, not in this context they are not. The connection string is the URL that will be used to conenct to the server. Look at the wording yourself in Excel.

Comment: @p.campbell: Yes, and I need to update the URL on the fly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1)
    .Connection = "URL;" & NewURL
    .Refresh
End With
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Followup questions: Can I refer to the connection in any other ways instead of `ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1)`? Maybe by name for example? And lastly, after I do the refresh I want to save the workbook so the user won't be prompted to do so when they close it but if I try `ThisWorkbook.Save` after your `With` block I get a message saying that the `Save` will cancel the pending `Refresh.` I guess it's trying to save before the refresh finishes. Is there a way I can handle this?

Comment: I would suggest you try recording a macro while creating a new web query. The recorded code will show you the options available: I think "Name" and "BackgroundQuery" are the properties you're interested in.  If you set BackgroundQuery to False then it should finish updating before your code moves on to the Save operation.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I just found the `Backgroundquery:=false` property and it works great.

Comment: I always get "Subscript out of range" when I do this. Any ideas?

Comment: @roviuser - I would guess there's no QueryTable on the active sheet.

Comment: @roviuser - In that case you should maybe start a new question and post your code, indicating the line which throws the error.